# Why the python script process enter the sleep state and can't be woken up for execution?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, process

This script is using grequests concurrent request url. And when it runs for 33 min, it goes to sleep permanently. And I don't no why. This script used to run well.

The main code is, :

```
urlList.append(grequests.get(url))
num = num + 1
if num = 50:
    resList = grequests.map(urlList, exception_handler=err_handler)
    num = 0
    urlList = []
```

The process status：

```
ps aux | grep build.py

work     27647  3.8  0.0 972736 29476 ?        Sl   Jan27  33:26 python build.py
```

```
strace -p 27647


Process 27647 attached
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1543747, 295274224}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1543747, 295337559}) = 0
epoll_wait(11, {}, 64, 59743)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1543807, 97334455}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1543807, 97428028}) = 0
epoll_wait(11, {}, 64, 59743)           = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1543866, 900111931}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1543866, 900158914}) = 0
```

env:

```
CentOS release 6.3
Python 2.7.13
grequests                     0.6.0
```